# How to change empty svg image placeholder

Tags: javascript, svg

I am using an image within a `<svg></svg>` block via an `<image xlink:href="" />` element.

The source is being set dynamically and can be empty at some points.
When it is empty, a pretty ugly placeholder is shown.

Is it possible to change it some way?

Comment: Please share some code (HTML/JS). Are you building the `svg` using javascript? Is there any CSS applied?

Comment: @Mottie no, it's just the source of an angular directive. You can easily see the effect here (broken image href leads to ugly placeholder): https://jsfiddle.net/mbnf2x7m/1/

Comment: If the source is set dynamically, change the code at that point so that it creates the entire image element rather than just setting the xlink:href of a pre-existing image element.